# how to html form post - file uploading and reading json response from php server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

i am trying file uploading to php my server.file and data uploading through multi part  /form-data ,the file and data received on php server but in my php server return json response .please help me how to read json response  in my webpage and if its success(code=0) means it redirect another page  .the php sever is common for both android and web pages .json response look like {"code":0,"message":"success"}

```
<div style="height:0px;overflow:hidden">
    <form id="myForm" action="http://192.168.2.4/digiid/api/addid" 
        method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" runat="server">

        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" onchange="showMyImage(this)" />
        <input type="hidden" name="userid" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["userid"]?>">
        <input type="hidden" id="inputfilename" name="filename" value="here">
    </form>
</div>

<a class="button1" id="browseButton" onclick=""  style="width:12%;height: 30px; text-decoration:none;"><font color="white" size="5px">Select ID</font></a>
<br/>

<div>

            <img src='images/capture_picture_size.png' id='imgscreen'  width='200' height='200'>

<br/>


<p id="filename" style="color: #ffffff; font-size: 20px" >
    Title of the ID<br/></p>

<a class="button1"onclick="myFunction()" style= " width:12%;height: 30px; text-decoration:none;"><font color="white" size="5px">Save ID</font></a></form>

</div>  

<script>
    function myFunction() {
       document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
    }
</script>

<script>
    browseButton.onclick=function chooseFile() {
        document.getElementById("file").click(); 
    };

    function showMyImage(fileInput) {

        var files = fileInput.files;

        var file = files[0];
        var imageType = /image.*/;

        var img=document.getElementById("imgscreen");
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (function(aImg) {
            return function(e) {
            //x=e.target.result

            img.src = e.target.result;
            var extfilename=file.name;
            document.getElementById("filename").innerHTML=extfilename.slice(0,-5) ;

            document.getElementById("inputfilename").value=extfilename.slice(0,-5);
     };
 })(img);

 reader.readAsDataURL(file);

 }</script>
```

Comment: What does the json response look like?

Comment: json response look like {"code":0,"message":"success"}

Comment: Can you please reformat your code? Why you try to access $_POST['photo'] ? There is no such input in your form. Access Fileuploads using $_FILE not $_POST

Comment: post your `php` server side code

Answer (score 5):

I think it should work for you. Using AJAX, as I do

```
     //Your php code
        $arrToJSON = array(
        "dataPHPtoJs"=>"yourData",
        "asYouWant"=>"<div class=\".class1\">soemting</div>"    
        );  
        return json_encode(array($arrToJSON));




    //Your javaScript code
    $(document).on("event", "#idElement", function(){
        //Data you want to send to php evaluate
         var dt={ 
                  ObjEvn:"btn_Login",
                  dataJsToPHP: $("#txt_EmailLogin").val()
                };

        //Ajax      
         var request =$.ajax({//http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
                                url: "yourServer.php",
                                type: "POST",
                                data: dt,
                                dataType: "json"
                            });

        //Ajax Done catch JSON from PHP 
            request.done(function(dataset){
                for (var index in dataset){ 
                     dataPHPtoJsJS=dataset[index].dataPHPtoJs;
                     asManyasYouWantJS=dataset[index].asYouWant;
                 }

                 //JavaScript conditions. Here you can control the behaivior of your html object, based on your PHP response
                 if(dataPHPtoJsJS){
                    $( "#idYourHtmlElement" ).removeClass( "class1" )
                    $( "#idYourHtmlElement" ).addClass( "class2" )
                 }


         }); 

        //Ajax Fail 
            request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
            }); 
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You should probably use an AJAX call. Here's a solution using jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#browseButton").click(function(){
        var url = "";
        var formdata = $("#myForm").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            data:  formdata,
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(response){
                if(response.status == "success"){
                    // Success

                } else {
                    // Failure

                }
            },
            error: function(response){
                // Error

            }          
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

In order to redirect the user, you can use: `window.location.href = " ... your_url ...";`

Here's an explanation on how to use jQuery AJAX and multi-part data:

[Sending multipart/formdata with jQuery.ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax)

Answer (score 1):

try [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

```
    $data = ({"code":0, "message":"success"});
    $array = json_decode($data, true);
```

by passing 2nd parameter to true you will get response in array instead of object.

the array will be then populated as follow:

```
    array (size=2)
    'code' => int 0
    'message' => string 'success' (length=7)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON response would be a kind of associative array in php. 
Encode your array data into JSON using "json_encode" and  return values as you want .

```
   $arr = array('status' => $status, 'status2' => $status2, );
   echo json_encode($arr);
```

NOTE:  If you are using ajax to call php file then do not use any php echo/print in that file and not even HTML. ECHO only "json_encode();" Nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

To sum it up:

1. Upload your data to server using AJAX with [native JS](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/uploading-files-ajax) (>=IE10) or [jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26143623/4112914)
2. Catch (xhr.responseText in [native JS](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/uploading-files-ajax)) and [parse the response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript)
3. Redirect with window.location.href="success.php"