# populate fields with last data row javascript php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a standard html form

```
<input type="radio" class="input" id="radiofill" name="radiofill" onclick="ajax('frm_tb_set_pgs','ajx-db/ajx-db_set_pgs_add_1.php','frm_type','tb_set_pgs','errmsg','','','','false','POST','false');"><label for="radiofill">&nbsp;Populate Data</label>
```

I would like the user to be able to press a radio button and fill in the form with the last 
data row in the mysql table.

the ajax function is as follows:

```
function buildPOST(theFormName, URLto) {
     var theForm = document.getElementById(theFormName);
     var qs = '';
     for (e = 0; e < theForm.elements.length; e++) {
         if (theForm.elements[e].name != '') {
             var name = theForm.elements[e].name;
             qs += (qs == '') ? '' : '&';
             qs += name + '=' + encodeURIComponent(theForm.elements[e].value);
         }
     }
     // qs+="\n"; 
     return qs;
 }

 function getobjval(value1, varname) {
     return '&' + varname + '=' + value1;
 }

 function ajax(theFormName, URLto, frm_type, varname, olddivid, newdivid, itemid, pgid, resetfrm, pgval, reloadopt) {
     var xmlMessage;
     var getvals;
     var gelm_var;
     var gelm;
     var selval;
     if (URLto.indexOf("?") == -1) {
         URLto = URLto + "?d=0";
     }
     xmlMessage = buildPOST(theFormName, URLto);
     if (itemid == '' || itemid == null) {} else {
         gelm = document.getElementById(itemid);
         //xmlMessage=xmlMessage+"&itemval="+gelm.value;
         switch (frm_type) {
             case "sel":
                 getvals = gelm.value;
                 break; //getvals = gelm.options[length].value; 
             case "addsel":
                 if (varname != null) {
                     gelm_var = document.getElementById(varname);
                     selval = gelm.options[gelm.selectedIndex].value;
                     //      xmlMessage = xmlMessage+getobjval(selval,varname)
                 }
                 break;
             case "but_add":
                 if (gelm.style.visibility = 'visible') {
                     gelm.style.visibility = 'hidden';
                 } else {}
                 break;

             case "none":

                 break;
         }
     }
     var oXMLHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest;
     oXMLHttpRequest.open(pgval, URLto + "&" + xmlMessage + "&varnm=" + varname, true);
     if (pgval == "POST") {

         //Send the proper header information along with the request
         oXMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
     }

     oXMLHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {

         if (this.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
             if (newdivid == null || newdivid == '') {
                 if (olddivid == null || olddivid == '') {} else {
                     var olddiv = document.getElementById(olddivid);
                     olddiv.innerHTML = '';
                     olddiv.innerHTML = this.responseText;
                 }
             } else {
                 var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
                 newdiv.innerHTML = this.responseText;
                 if (olddivid == null || olddivid == '') {} else {

                     var olddiv = document.getElementById(olddivid);
                     olddiv.innerHTML = '';
                     document.getElementById(newdivid).appendChild(newdiv);
                     olddiv.parentNode.removeChild(olddiv);
                 }
             }
             //         document.getElementById(itemid).options.focus();}

         }
         if (resetfrm == 'true') {
             document.forms[1].reset();
         }
     }
     oXMLHttpRequest.send(xmlMessage);

     if (reloadopt == 'true') {
         document.location.reload();
     }
 }
```

so the radio button calls the following php:

```
ajx-db_set_pgs_add_1.php

    <?php include ("../php_01_db_hdr.php"); 
 include ("../inc.php"); 

$sel_fldnm ="pg_id";
$sel_tbnm ="tb_set_pgs";
if (isset($_POST['fldnm'])) {
$sel_fldnm = $_POST['fldnm'];}
if (isset($_POST['tbnm'])) {
$sel_tbnm = $_POST['tbnm'];}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `".$sel_tbnm."` ORDER BY `".$sel_fldnm."` DESC LIMIT 1";
    foreach( $db->query($sql) as $dbrow ) {
        $dblist_pg_url = clean(($dbrow['pg_url']));
        $dblist_pg_fldr_id = clean(intval($dbrow['pg_fldr_id']));
        $dblist_pg_icn_flnm = clean(($dbrow['pg_icn_flnm']));
        $dblist_pg_alt_icn_flnm = clean(($dbrow['pg_alt_icn_flnm']));
        $dblist_pg_icn_szwd = clean(intval($dbrow['pg_icn_szwd']));
        $dblist_pg_icn_szht = clean(intval($dbrow['pg_icn_szht']));
        $dblist_pg_dt_crtd = clean(($dbrow['pg_dt_crtd']));
        $dblist_pg_dt_tmst = clean(($dbrow['pg_dt_tmst']));
    } 


header('Pragma: no-cache'); 

?><script type="text/javascript" src="../js/std.js"></script><script>

populatefields ("pg_dt_tmst", '<?php echo $dblist_pg_dt_tmst; ?>');
populatefields ("pg_dt_crtd", '<?php echo $dblist_pg_dt_crtd; ?>');
populatefields ("pg_icn_szht", '<?php echo $dblist_pg_icn_szht; ?>');
populatefields ("pg_icn_szwd", '<?php echo $dblist_pg_icn_szwd; ?>');
populatefields ("pg_alt_icn_flnm", '<?php echo $dblist_pg_alt_icn_flnm; ?>');
populatefields ("pg_icn_flnm", '<?php echo $dblist_pg_icn_flnm; ?>');
populatefields ("pg_fldr_id", '<?php echo $dblist_pg_fldr_id; ?>');
populatefields ("pg_url", '<?php echo $dblist_pg_url; ?>');

// etc......

</script>
```

the function populate fields is as follows:

```
function populatefields (fldnm, datavalue) {
        var elem_id = document.getElementById(fldnm);
            elem_id.value = datavalue;         
}
```

problem is that when you click the elements in the form do not get altered.

any help to get the ajax working would be amazing.
Thanks

Comment: What is the server sending back, errors? Have you looked at the response data in your ajax call, or in a dev tool? I'm having trouble making out how the code flows. It's a bit of a mess.

Comment: Assigning to `.innerHTML` doesn't run scripts in the HTML.

Comment: Instead of returning Javascript, return JSON. Then put code in your callback function that fills in the appropriate fields from the JSON object.

Comment: thanks Bamar - how do you return JSON?

Comment: How to return JSON, see in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26052722/how-to-html-form-post-file-uploading-and-reading-json-response-from-php-server/26152958#26152958 .... use '$arrToJSON = array("html2Js"=>"<div class=\".class1\">soemting</div>" ) return json_encode(array($arrToJSON));'

Comment: thanks for the help
in the end I used http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_example.asp
and parsed the data in the ajax script file